# Copying all same files to one location and changing the file name to subdirectory_filename

Tags: shell, command-line, file-management

I have conf.yml files in different folders as below.

```
/var/loyalty-badge/conf/conf.yml
/var/loyalty-level/conf/conf.yml
/var/promotion/conf/conf.yml
/var/featured/conf/conf.yml
```

Now I want all the `conf.yml` to copy one folder like conf

Destination files should be like

```
conf/loyalty-badge_conf.yml
conf/loyalty-level_conf.yml
conf/promotion_conf.yml
conf/featured_conf.yml
```

Can you please suggest a script for it.

Comment: Can you please give me a basic idea of how to start with this problem

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please take a moment and look through our [help] or take the [tour]. This is not a forum in the traditional sense and is not a free script-writing service either. We expect askers to expend some effort before asking here. So, please [edit] your question and show us what you've tried so far, what your google searches have shown you and which part, specifically, is giving you trouble. For example, I assume you know how to use the `mv` command, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [wildcard pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) to enumerate the `…/conf/conf.yml` files. Use a [for loop](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) to iterate over the files.

```
for x in /var/*/conf/conf.yml; do …
```

You need to extract the part just after `/var`. You can do it with [shell expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) features: prefix and suffix removal. Do it in two steps: remove the `/var` prefix, and remove the `/conf/conf.yml` suffix.

```
y=${x#/var}; y=${y%%/*}
```

Now glue it all together.

```
for x in /var/*/conf/conf.yml; do …
  y=${x#/var}; y=${y%%/*}
  cp -p "$x" "conf/${y}_conf.yml"
done
```

Note that the braces are necessary in `${y}_conf.yml`, since `$y_conf.yml` would be parsed as “the value of `y_conf` followed by the text `.yml`”.